# Pass SQL Login as parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm not too experienced with MS SQL, so I do apologize if it's a very stupid question to ask - but I couldn't any real info about it on the Intenet.

So, I'm just trying to create a SQL Login and SQL User for that login and it goes like that:

```
SqlCommand CreateDatabaseUser = new SqlCommand("CREATE LOGIN @NewUserLogin " + 
                                               "WITH PASSWORD = '@NewUserPassword' " + 
                                               "CREATE USER @NewUserLogin FOR LOGIN @NewUserLogin", AddUserConnection);
CreateDatabaseUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewUserLogin", NewUserLoginTextbox.Text);
CreateDatabaseUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewUserPassword", PasswordTextbox.Text);

AddUserConnection.Open();
CreateDatabaseUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And I get an error saying `Incorrect syntax near '@NewUserLogin'`, but if I do it incorrect and unsafe way like that:

```
"CREATE LOGIN " + NewUserLoginTextbox.Text +
" WITH PASSWORD = '" + PasswordTextbox.Text + "'" +                                                    
" CREATE USER " + NewUserLoginTextbox.Text + " FOR LOGIN " + NewUserLoginTextbox.Text
```

then it DOES work!

So, I wanna figure out what I'm doing work there. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CREATE` statemen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879262.aspx)t is a [`Data Definition Language` (DDL) statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx).

[`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) are supported for *[Data manipulation language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language)* operations not *[Data definition language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)* operations.

Data manipulation language =

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...
UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Data definition language =

```
CREATE TABLE ... 
DROP TABLE ... ;
ALTER TABLE ... ADD ... INTEGER;
```

*AFAIK*, there is no way to write this with parameters. You need to use them as part of the SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply! Can you please tell me, what is the right way to deal with DDL statements to make then injection-safe?

Comment: @Stutz You should either perform _very very_ stringent validation on the user name and password before putting it into the SQL, or have a whitelisted set of valid user names and passwords, in order to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks again! You are being so very helpful! :) Thou, I was hoping there's some in-built tools to validate it in C#!.. Welp, guess I have to do it manually!